# Avoiding Shotgun Surgery with Database.SetInitializer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

The [canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8679662/161457) on where to put `Database.SetInitializer` calls is in `Global.asax` for web projects. I'm looking for another option.

We're using Entity Framework 4.3.1 with Code First. We write web services and WinForms applications, and typically put data access code (such as DbContexts) in shared libraries.

Currently, the constructors of our DbContext descendants look like this:

```
public PricingContext(string connectionString)
    : base(connectionString)
{
    Database.SetInitializer<PricingContext>(null);
}
```

95% of the time, that's the right default. 5% of the time (some integration tests, greenfield development, etc.) it's not.

If we move that code into the initialization (or configuration) of our services and applications, adding a new DbContext to a library involves [Shotgun Surgery](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ShotgunSurgery). All of these projects have to be updated, even if the library doesn't expose the context directly.

Optional arguments are one possibility:

```
public PricingContext(string connectionString,
    IDatabaseInitializer<PricingContext> databaseInitializer = null)
    : base(connectionString)
{
    Database.SetInitializer<PricingContext>(databaseInitializer);
}
```

Overriding the default strategy might involve passing the initializer through multiple layers, though.

We've also considered creating a reflection-based initializer that would set all contexts to a specific strategy.

What's the best practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about creating a DBContextBootstrapper class that you can instantiate in Global.asax of every project; which in its implementation sets initializer for every context.

This way if you add a new dbcontext you have to make change in the bootstrapper only, not in every project.

Comment: Thank you! After trying this and much discussion, we decided to go with setting initializers at the locations where DbContexts are being created (or where a DI/IoC Container is being configured). At that point, we know what the contexts are. So my original question was based on faulty assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

EF 4.3 (and newer) also includes possibility to [define initializer from configuration file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/01/12/ef-4-3-configuration-file-settings.aspx) so you will not need to set it in code at all but it will still require you to maintain multiple configs.

@Hasan's advice looks like the best solution for you.