# How to generate membership provider tables in my database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to get grip on mvc4 , i just created a new `Internet Application` using asp.net mvc4 . I want to know that how to generate `SimpleMemberShipProvider`  in asp.net mvc4 . They added a new class in `Filter` folder named  `SimpleMembershipInitializer` but i don't know how to generate tables using that class .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: I edited my answer to provide some extra background. If you are using the Internet Application template in MVC4 then it will create a localdb database in your App_Data folder the first time you run it, so you don't need to create your own db - the whole thing will be done for you.

Comment: @AndyBrown yes you are right , it create a defaultconnection.mdf file but when i look into that database , there is only one table name `UserProfile` and there's only two fields in it named `UserId , UserName` , Where is the rest of membership Tables  ?

Comment: Have you registered a new user yet?

Comment: Shit Man , Wasted my hour , now when tried to Register a user , i automatically creates everything  Thanks alot . Thanks again

Comment: I have now emphasised this in my answer. To save yourself more time later, I suggest looking at the references in my answer, and especially consider code-first and merging UserProfile into your `DbContext`

Comment: @AndyBrown if i go through the procedure that hasbeen told in `code-first scenario` link , then i that case membership tables will be created or not ?

Comment: Best so ask a new question on that one - it is OT for your original question. Short answer is yes (as long as you set it all up correctly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have created your database, and set your connection string in `web.config` to that database, then when you first go to `Account/Login` it will generate the tables for you. Note that not all tables will be generated until you first create a user through "Register", then you will also see the tables starting with `webpages_`

**EDIT** If you are using the Internet Application template in MVC4 then it the default template is going to set you up with a localdb in the App_Data folder. This will be created the first time you run the application and call a database. (end edit)

Have a look at my answer [here to "How do I use my own database with SimpleMembership and WebSecurity? What is MVC4 security all about?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16734651/1945631) to get an overview of SimpleMembership and how it all fits together.

Note that if you don't call `Account/Login`, then the database will not initialise, therefore in certain circumstances you will need to initialise it yourself, you can use the following lines in your `Application_Start` in global.asax.cs, or see my answer [here to "ASP.NET MVC 4, The “WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection” method can be called only once"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16512694/1945631) for more comprehensive scenarios.

```
if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
{
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("myConnectionStringName", "Users", "UserId", "Email", autoCreateTables: true);
}
```

Alternatively you can register `InitializeSimpleMembership` as a [global filter](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx), which would have the same effect as using the above code in global.asax.cs.

`InitializeSimpleMembership` simply does the above lines of code for you, but because it is only decorating the `AccountController` in the template provided, it will only kick in if you visit one of the Actions on that controller. This is where most of us trip up the first time. The MVC Internet Application template is only providing a sample way of using it. You need to actually ensure it is used across the entire site in order to have a production ready system.

---

*Footnote:*

Now that you've started using SimpleMembership it is worth knowing straight away that it works best in a [code-first scenario](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx), and that it is easiest to immediately put the UserProfile model class into your own DbContext that you are using for all the other Models in your code; this will prevent a lot of problems for you later. I will leave you to ask more questions on this separately as it is slightly off-topic.

Note that you can use the same connection string name for both your DbContext and the SimpleMembership (by default this is called "DefaultConnection" in the visual studio project template).

Answer (score 0):

1) If you provide a default connection string in the web.config, the membership will create the database automacaly at the first login!

2) If you dont provide any connection, the app will look for the default connection in the machine.config to create the database at the SQL Instance or elsewhere mapped there.

3) If you need to create a custom MemberShipProvider take a look here: [SimpleMembership, Membership Providers,](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx)

Hopes this help you!