# need another connection string to use simple membership provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string, sqlconnection, simplemembership

I am new to ASP.net MVC.
In my MVC application I wanted to have default login functions.
 Already I have connection string like this for my entity framework connection to application,

```
<add name="TestDB2Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntittyModel.SchoolDBModel.csdl|res://*/EntittyModel.SchoolDBModel.ssdl|res://*/EntittyModel.SchoolDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=PRAGEETH-PC;initial catalog=TestDB2;user id=sa;password=sa123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Using that connection string I try to use the available function of default pre implemented login functions. I could not use that and show me following error.

> “Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may
>   not be installed.”

Then I try to create a new connection string as follow and then it worked fine,

```
<add name="TestDB2Entities1"    connectionString="data source=PRAGEETH-PC;initial catalog=TestDB2;uid=sa;pwd=sa123;integrated security=sspi" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

But I need to have only one connection string to suit for both scenarios. Is it possible to have one connection string instead of having two connection strings?Or is it ok to have multiple connection string in my application?

Comment: "Default preimplemented Login functions"... by this do you mean the the Built In functionalities of Forms Authentication, MemberShip, Profiles etc.. ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong using 2 connectionstrings in 1 project!

Comment: Hi FlopScientist,I mean the MVC 4 SimpleMembershipProvider.

Comment: Hi Dylan,but those two connection string is representing same database.so I don't feel it good choice.but I do not have good knowledge about that.

Answer (score 0):

Prageeth,

Assuming you mean the default implementation from the MVC 4 Internet Application template in Visual Sutdio 2012, then you can (and should) have a single connection string. In the template the only one initially is in `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute`, but you will need to add more (see the footnote)

All you need to do is set the connection string name  in your `UsersContext` class to that of your own. Do the same in the `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute` class, and also in any calls to `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection`

If you are using code-first (which, by the way, is the simplest approach when you first use SimpleMembership) you can also:

- move `UserProfile` from `UsersContext` into your own context, and delete `UsersContext`
- change the references to `UsersContext` in `AccountController` and `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute` to your own context

*Footnote*

For more information about what SimpleMembership is, and how it works, see my answer to the question [How do I use my own database with SimpleMembership and WebSecurity? What is MVC4 security all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16734651/1945631), and for the simplest way to use InitializeSimpleMembership, see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16512694/1945631)