# How to store new users into database from Configuration in MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, csv, asp.net-identity

I have a model which inherits from ApplicaitonUser, and is defined as following:

```
public class Business : ApplicationUser
{
    ...
}
```

Then, in my configuration I'm reading all the information from an CSV file, and creating a List of Business objects. Then, I want to create all of them as new users and add to the database, and give them a default password (I fill later e-mail all the users in the list their password, so they can change it). I guess I need to user UserManager.CreateAsync method, but I cannot seem to be able to reference it from my Configuration file.

At the moment, I have something like this, where I read all the Business specific information from the CSV file:

```
        foreach (string csv in csvs)
        {
            using (CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(csv))
            {
                foreach (string[] values in reader.RowEnumerator)
                {
                    businesses.Add(new Business
                    {
                        BusinessName = values[0],
                        Email = values[1],
                        Address = values[2],
                        City = values[3],
                        StateID = states.Single(s => s.StateCode == values[4]).StateID,
                        Zip = values[5],
                        Phone = values[6],
                        Fax = values[7],
                        SICCode = values[8],
                        Description = values[9],
                        Website = values[10]
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

Then, I guess I need a foreach statement similar to the one below, to go over all the Businesses, but I don't know whether this is right method to go, and even if it is, how can I access the UserManager from Configuration.cs file? I cannot seem to be able to access it from Configuration.

```
        foreach (Business b in businesses)
        {
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(b, "MyPassword");
        }
```

Comment: can you add a password field to the Business Class and assign it a default when creating new Business { } can you show how Business is fully defined please

Comment: @DJKRAZE My Business class includes all the above fields. Except for Email. The point is that it inherits from ApplicationUser, so it also has all the fields of it, from there comes the Email field. My question is how can I create new users and store them in database from Configuration file. I think I need something like below foreach statement. But, I simply cannot get to UserManager from my Configuration file. Setting default password is not a problem, while CreateAsync accepts two parameter, one ApplicationUser and one string which is the password.

Comment: When you say Configuration.cs file, what do you mean?  Are you trying to seed the database?

Comment: @ett It's a little late, but I posted an answer about how to seed a database using the EF configuration file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for accessing UserManager, you can create a new:

```
new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
```

Or get the one from the current HttpContext if this is setup appropriately in Startup.Auth.cs:

```
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
```

Now if this is seed data, this kind of logic should probably not be within the web application itself. If you do want to do the seeding programmatically by reading a csv-file, consider writing a separate console application that you have locally together with your csv-file, and run this whenever you need to do this seeding for a particular db.

Then you could also skip this ApplicationUser infrastructure with UserManager, and for simplicity only generate a database-first model of the database you are working with and have EF insert the data as usual.

Edit: Oh yeah, the password thing. So you could still use the UserManager infrastructure to solve everything, or you could use [UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword("Password")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.ipasswordhasher%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) manually if you want to go around the other parts of UserManager.

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted solution works, I think this offers a better option.  Here is an article about seeding your database that I used: [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).  Below is a breakdown of code that I use to match your situation.

In your DbContext constructor you can specify a database initializer that references your Configuration.cs file.  You have several options for the type of initializer, you can find out about them [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx).

```
    public ApplicationDBContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDBContext, IBCF.Core.Migrations.Configuration>());
    }
```

Once you have specified that, in your configuration file, you can add a seed function that populates your database with the items from the CSV.  Doing this will allow you to seed data to your database without having to put code in your web project and without having to create a separate application.

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<IBCF.Core.ApplicationDBContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(IBCF.Core.ApplicationDBContext context)
    {
        //Initialize managers
        var userManager = new UserManager<Business>(new UserStore<Business>(context));

        //Do something to populate your csvs variable

        foreach (string csv in csvs)
        {
            using (CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(csv))
            {
                foreach (string[] values in reader.RowEnumerator)
                {
                    var business = new Business
                    {
                        BusinessName = values[0],
                        Email = values[1],
                        Address = values[2],
                        City = values[3],
                        StateID = states.Single(s => s.StateCode == values[4]).StateID,
                        Zip = values[5],
                        Phone = values[6],
                        Fax = values[7],
                        SICCode = values[8],
                        Description = values[9],
                        Website = values[10]
                    };

                    userManager.Create(business, "MyPassword")
                }
            }
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at it. I was also following a similar approach. I will let you know of the results.

Comment: I agree that this is a viable method, but should Database.SetInitializer really be inside the constructor of the DbContext? Shouldn't it be better to have it in Application_Start in Global.asax?

Comment: This question has some good comments about where to put the Initializer. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679562/place-to-put-database-setinitializer)  Overall, I think it's a matter of preference / project configuration.