# IdentityDbContext doesn't call the seed method from my database initializer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, autofac, asp.net-identity-2

I'm trying to set initial user with admin role using Entity Framework, Autofac and Identity 2.0
Here my Application Context class:

```
public class ApplicationContext<TUser> : IdentityDbContext<TUser> where TUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationContext(string conectionString) : base(conectionString) 
    { 
        Database.SetInitializer(new MyContextInitializer()); 
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //entities builder and configuration
    }
}
```

And my custom initializer:

```
class MyContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationContext<IdentityUser>>
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationContext<IdentityUser> context)
    {
        //seeding data
    }
}
```

The problem is that the seed method is never called. Whats going on and how to fix that? Thanks for advance!

Comment: I don't think it's possible if you leave generic in your application context - `ApplicationContext<TUser>` is not implicitely convertible to `ApplicationContext<IdentityUser>`. You can probably add generic parameter to MyContextInitializer and use TUser for its Seed method - can't check right now though.

Comment: @raderick thanks for your replying but I deleted generic type from context and everything ok!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understanding, you must call `Database.SetInitializer()` *before* any instance is created (including in the constructor).

One way is to use a static constructor:

```
public class ApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext<TUser> 
  where TUser : IdentityUser
{
  static ApplicationContext()
  { 
    Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationContext>(new MyContextInitializer()); 
  }
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    //entities builder and configuration
  }
}
```

Comment: Good catch. That's where mine is too.

Comment: @SteveGreene Idk why but the problem went away when I remove `<TUser>` type from ApplicationContext class.

Comment: That maybe so, but the static constructor (or Global.asax) is a much better location or that code will be run every time you construct an instance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679562/place-to-put-database-setinitializer

Comment: I don't prefer the code in Global.asax, the class should be self sufficient.  Otherwise anyone else using the same Context will get different results from the same class.

Comment: @SteveGreene Thank you. But you need to delete public modifier and generic type. With `<TUser>` it doesn't work.

Comment: @user3818229 Yes, I get that. Do you get my point about static versus instance?

Comment: Not really:( As I can understand static constructor calls only once (during object creating by autofac in my sources). So whats the problem?

Comment: Thanks @ErikPhilips. Can you please tell me in this instance where the connection string should go?

Comment: @dalcam you should click the ask-a-question button in the upper right, present code in your example and reference this question.  Asking a question of that magnitude in a comment won't get you much help.

Comment: Hi @ErikPhilips, I just thought that it fit in your answer here because the asker of this question has it in his sample and it was missing in your answer....

Comment: @dalcam there would be no difference.  I simply didn't include it as it has nothing to do with the answer.