# Unable to disable code-first migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

Reading through many answers here it appears that in order to disable code-first migrations I must only add the line `Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);` 
to my context class.  Despite having done so, I am still seeing errors like below.

```
Error OracleException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist 
Time 717ms 
Details 
   SELECT "GROUPBY1"."A1" AS "C1" FROM ( SELECT COUNT(1) AS "A1" FROM
   "DBO"."__MIGRATIONHISTORY" "EXTENT1" ) "GROUPBY1"
```

And

```
Error OracleException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist 
Time 0ms 
Details 
    SELECT * FROM ( SELECT "PROJECT1"."C1" AS "C1", "PROJECT1"."MODELHASH" AS 
    "MODELHASH" FROM ( SELECT "EXTENT1"."MODELHASH" AS "MODELHASH", CAST( 
    "EXTENT1"."ID" AS NUMBER(10,0)) AS "C1" FROM "DBO"."EDMMETADATA" "EXTENT1" ) 
    "PROJECT1" ORDER BY "PROJECT1"."C1" DESC ) WHERE (ROWNUM <= (1) )
```

Of course the root cause is that my database (Oracle) does not contain `__MIGRATIONHISTORY` or `MODELHASH`.  There is a similar question [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dc5f5082-3fb8-45e6-b912-141235527f8a/invalid-object-name-dboedmmetadata-and-dbomigrationhistory?forum=adodotnetentityframework) that suggests the same initialization but there is no additional follow-up.

The setup of my classes are as follows.

```
public class AContext : MyContext 
{
    public DbSet<> .... { get;set; }

    public override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Mapping());
    }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected MyContext() : base("name=Entities")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
    }
}
```

What else am I missing?

Comment: You using 2 contexts? Make sure the initializer runs before either is first accessed. Also, move `SetInitializer` from the instance constructor to a [static constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors).

Comment: It's not two contexts.  It's just inherited to set the common values among all contexts that are defined in the datalayer.  Only one is used at a time though.

Comment: Is this MVC? If so, try moving your initializer to Application_Start in Global.asax. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679562/place-to-put-database-setinitializer).

Comment: It's a common library called from a Web Api 2 app right now.  I'll check the link.  Thanks