# MVC issue for accessing the data from database:The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am working on MVC where I am trying to access data from the database. I am new to MVC. I am getting the following error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int32)' in 'MVCDemo1.Controllers.EmployeeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>
> Parameter name: parameters

Code:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MVCDemo1.Models.EmployeeContext>(null);
```

I have added the above line in `global.asax.cs` file and I am getting the error there.

The below is my Model:Employee.cs

```
namespace MVCDemo1.Models
{
    [Table("tblEmployee")]
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The below is my code for the Controller:EmployeeController

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {                    
                EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
                Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.Single(x =>           x.EmployeeId == id);

                return View(employee);
                            
    }
```

The below code is for View:details.cshtml

```
@model MVCDemo1.Models.Employee

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Employee Details";
    }
    
    <h2>Employee Details</h2>
    
    <table style="font-family:Arial">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Employee ID:
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.EmployeeId
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.Name
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Gender:
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.Gender
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                City:
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.City
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

My Route configPath is:

```
defaults: new { controller = "Employee", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Can anyone enlighten me with this error?

I tried by removing `id = UrlParameter.Optional` from routeconfig but not worked for me.

Comment: Please provide a test url that fails for you. ie  http `GET` `"/Employee/Details/4"`

Answer (score 2):

The error is coming from the MVC framework, and has nothing to do with your database configuration. As the error states, you have a non-nullable argument for your action, an `int`, and you are not sending a value for it. This can happen if you make HTTP calls to this action without providing a value for `id`, e.g. through a query string in the URL, or otherwise invoking the method. Leaving `id = UrlParameter.Optional` lets you do that. If you remove this, you might see another error, suggesting where this is coming from.

Comment: ...It shows me error in global.asax.cs file... Database.SetInitializer<MVCDemo1.Models.EmployeeContext>(null);

Comment: @chetankambli What part of Global.asax? `Application_BeginRequest`?

Comment: protected void Application_Start()
        {
         
           Database.SetInitializer<MVCDemo1.Models.EmployeeContext>(null);
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }

Comment: @chetankambli this is still coming from the MVC framework, like I said. I don't know why you see it on this line. What do you see if you remove `id = UrlParameter.Optional`?

Comment: @chetankambli try moving this call to a **static** constructor of your `EmployeeContext`. You can also use `Database.SetInitializer(new NullDatabaseInitializer<EmployeeContext>());` to declare no database initializer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679562

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193247/discussion-between-tsahi-asher-and-chetan-kambli).

Answer (score 1):

if your id parameter can be null then you have to make it nullable type and check before querying employee table

```
 public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    { 
     if(id != null)
      {                   
       EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
       Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.Single(x =>x.EmployeeId == id);

            return View(employee);
     }
    else {
      return  SomeView();
     }

}
```

Comment: ..EmployeeId is a primary key

Comment: i am talking about the parameter 'id'

Answer (score 0):

One more thing: I would not just create a new instance of your EmployeeContext. You could get this using dependency injection.

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly EmployeeContext _context;

    public MyController(EmployeeContext context)
    {
      _context = context;
    }

    ...
}
```

Check out Microsoft's documentation on this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext